# ImageView: Drawable and padding?

Tags: android, android-imageview, padding, android-drawable

I wrote a custom drawable and display it in an ImageView.

If I add a padding to the ImageView, my drawable overdraw the padding and fills the complete image view.

What I do in my drawable is:

```
@Override
public void setBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);

    Rect r = new Rect();

    getPadding(r);

    Log.d("Test", "padding " + r.toShortString());

    mWidth = right - left;
    mHeight = bottom - top;

}
```

and in the Drawables draw method I draw a Bitmap to fill mWidth and mHeight.

So how do I take padding into count?
getPadding(r); returns always 0,0,0,0 values even if the ImageView has some padding.

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

getPadding() can only be called after the Imageview has been loaded. Add a ViewTreeObserver to get the padding after the imageview has been loaded.

Comment: Im overriding Drawable.setBounds() and not about the ImageView.setBounds(), or did you mean something different?